# BlobItem from an URI

Tags: .net-core, azure-blob-storage

How do I get the `BlobItem` for which I know the full name/URI?
I have AccountName, AccountKey available to me; I can generate a SAS URI if needed.

- The *blobContainerClient*.GetBlobs(prefix: $"{fullName}").Single(); seems the straightforward way but this is actually a query which (at scale) is costly
- The BlobModelsFactory seems to be explicitly made for mocking purposes
- BlobItem does not have a constructor nor publicly settable properties

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the following: 1) Are you using simple blob URI or is it a SAS URI and 2) Do you have access to storage account credentials?

Comment: Question updated; I have AccountName, AccountKey available to me; I can generate a SAS URI if needed. I have full access to the storage account.

Comment: Just curious, what you want to do with BlobItem?

Comment: My application does all sorts of things with [lots of] blockblobs (list names, size, tier, folder, uri, ...). I could create a custom BlobItem with all of these properties but that would be like reinventing the wheel; alternatively I could settle with a BlobClient (doing much of the same) but is a heavier object. -- Regardless of the representation, curious how to get a BlobItem / why getting it is not straightforward

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. Even if you were able to create an instance of BlobItem, I don't think it would be of much use. All the properties will be initialized to default values (e.g. size would be zero bytes). You have to fetch blob properties from the server to get actual values and for that you will need to use BlobClient.

Comment: I don't see why there is no equivalent for `blobContainerClient.GetBlob(fullName)` (note GetBlob, singular)

Comment: . Please don’t get me started on the new SDK. It is one of most unfriendly SDKs I’ve seen.

Comment: So could the solution that getting properties of a blob by its URI meet your requirement? Basically it covers all properties of `BlobItem`

Comment: I fully agree with you Gaurav on the SDK. The CLI is even worse. Stanley, see comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below to get the properties of a blob:

```
   var blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri("<Blob URI with sas token>"));

    var blobProperties = blobClient.GetProperties().Value;
```

Comment: Tx Stanley, I ran some BenchmarkDotNet tests of `blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(prefix:fullName).Properties` vs `new BlobClient(fullName).GetProperties().Value`. In conclusion they are about the same (both time/memory/http calls). Consideration 1: the GetBlobs is a LIST call and is more expensive (0.050$/10k ops) and the GetProperties is at 0.004$/10k ops.
Consideration 2: GetBlobs gets more info in 1 call vs blobClient.Exist() is a 2nd call - doubling the total time vs GetBlobs, and depending on the use case these will all be additional calls. In conclusion, I'm not sure yet how to proceed

Comment: @WouterVanRanst, I see, I think you can call `get-blob-properties` rest API directly:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties , if a blob not exists or has been removed, you will get 404 and no need to call `Exist()` function.

Comment: Thanks Stanley. I accepted this as an answer. FWIW/FYI I created a custom adapter for BlobItem and BlobClient that hide the implementation details.

Comment: @WouterVanRanst, glad to help,thanks for the info and have a nice day buddy